# Core Location opt-in protocol

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is there any documentation the defines the protocol followed by iPhone OS to obtain the Core Location opt-in from the user?

I've observed that the user is shown a dialog the first two times an application is run.  The dialog asks the user if it's OK for that particular application to use location information.  Once the user has approved the application the second time the framework treats that as a permanent opt-in.

Is this behavior officially documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've seen the description in the [CLLocationManager class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) documentation? It's not too specific on the details though...

> **Important:** The user has the option of
>   denying an application’s access to the
>   location service data. During its
>   initial uses by an application, the
>   Core Location framework prompts the
>   user to confirm that using the
>   location service is acceptable. If the
>   user denies the request, the
>   CLLocationManager object reports an
>   appropriate error to its delegate
>   during future requests.

Comment: I needed to know the details, the question was originally to answer a question from the legal team. They wanted to ensure that the opt-in protocol was in line with the existing guidelines of the organization.  Thank you though! that's the best answer so far!